# Why is the length of an array 0 after a assign a key/value pair? (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var array = new Array()
array.name = 'peter'
console.log(array.length) //returns 0
console.log(array.name) //returns peter
```

I would've expected the length to be 1 and not 0. Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: You are mixing object and array syntax. Expect the unexpected.

Comment: Did you mean to do `array.push({name: 'peter'})` ?

Comment: for set the array value to an array you must use index as a property like this: `array[0] = 'peter'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to push value to array.

array.push({name:'peter'});

Answer (score 1):

That merely add a property name to instance of that array object.  To actually add item to the array to increase its size, you need to push item into it.  Something like, array.push('peter').